# Timestamp mismatch on table names

Tags: database, bash, shell, unix

The table created by script A using `bq` command is `20220601202945_table1` in big query.Let's assume it's done.

```
table1= 20220601202945_table1
```

script B: goes like this

```
process_start_time=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`

table2=${process_start_time}_table2
table2_sql="${BASEDIR}/sql/table2.sql"

bq query --nouse_legacy_sql \
--project_id=${gcp_project_id} \
--destination_table=${gcp_dataset}.${table2} \
"${table2_sql}"
```

table2.sql: goes like below

```
select * from `${gcp_project_id}.${gcp_dataset}.${table1}`
```

When i execute the job, as per the current date and time, query in table2.sql fills like following

```
select * from `sample.test.20220601203045_table1`
```

Due to one minute gap in between both the scripts execution, the table name is affected in table2.sql .And the job has to be executed on daily basis, hardcoding is not possible. Scripts are triggered by control-M

Comment: I have no idea about what problem you really want to solve - but - if you want `B` to not miss any log entries, let `B` save the timestamp between queries, so that the next time it asks the database, it'll ask for "give me everything since _old-timestamp_ up until _new-timestamp_" and receives the data and saves _new-timestamp_. Next time, the saved timestamp acts as _old-timestamp_.

Comment: Why would someone name the table with the timestamp? At first cursory glance that sounds like a design problem. Fix the *design* with these needs and constraints in mind. -- since you probably don't have that option, we may need more information to design a workaround.

Comment: "table1 acts a an input for B script" How? passed as argument by name? Take some time to read about a [Minimum reproducible example](/help/mcve)

Comment: Show the code instead of describing what your scripts are supposed to do. How do the scipts get executed? Manually? From some other software? By `cron`? Maybe you can use a wrapper script that calls scripts A and B with suitable arguments?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is `B` supposed to retrieve? The last table added by `A`?

Comment: I have made changes on the post which is not an actual code simply a similar pattern of original, for easy understanding i used this, hope it gives u a better idea. As paul pointed to design flaw, tbh  I'm not in a position to alter it. I just wanted to know is there any way before reporting that to my team.

Comment: in shell (bash included), assigning a value to a variable is down with `var=value`, no space around the `=`.  Could that be it?  When you assign table1 here, you have a space after `=`.